# How to get list of products in a particular category in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of products under a `categoryID`, how can I get the display the product under each `categoryID`

This is my category id data **:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "category": {
        "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
        "products": [],
        "type": "mobile phone",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

This is the product data with `categoryID` **:**

```
{
    "_id": "62567252370e769a8a93a517",
    "category": {
        "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
        "products": [],
        "type": "mobile phone",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "title": "galaxy s10",
}
```

this my html template to display my data

```
 <div>
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{category.type}}</p>
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product._id"
        >
          {{ product.title }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I get the `{{ category.type }}`, but when looping through the product I get all the products from my database instead of the products in a particular `categoryID`

How can I display the list of product under `{{ category.type }}` each time I go to the categoryID route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    category: {
      "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
      "products": [],
      "type": "mobile phone",
      "__v": 0
    },
    products: [{
      "_id": "62567252370e769a8a93a517",
      "category": {
        "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
        "products": [],
        "type": "mobile phone",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "title": "galaxy s10"
    }, {
      "_id": "62567252370e769a8a93a517",
      "category": {
        "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
        "products": [],
        "type": "mobile phone",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "title": "One Plus"
    }]
  },
  mounted() {
    const catID = category._id;
    this.products = this.products.filter(({ category }) => catID === category._id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{category.type}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="product in products" :key="product._id">
      {{ product.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but I am getting category is not defined.  https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/9751/cIxfqH.jpg  ... this my script tag https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6266/AXgEEM.jpg .... my html template https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/9199/okXlAi.jpg

Comment: @xander Few observations as per 2nd screenshot : 1) category should be an object. Hence, define it `category: {}` instead of `category: []` in data. 2) Use `const catID = this.category._id` instead of `const catID = category._id`

Comment: Hello, with this I'm still getting all the products in my database if I for loop products, it's not filtering can I send the hosted backend url?

Comment: @xander Can you please share the screenshot of console.log for `this.category` and `this.products`. So that i can check what's the issue. I think you have to call this filter code inside the success response of `products` axios call. As, axios calls are asynchronous. Hence, your filter code is  calling before the axios calls.